# How to resolve "Please activate LaTeX Workshop sidebar item to render the thumbnail of a PDF file" in VS Code？

Tags: viewers, vscode

I'm currently using the LaTeX Workshop extension in Visual Studio Code for my LaTeX projects. Recently, I've encountered an issue where I'm unable to preview PDF files embedded in my .tex document. The error message I receive is "Please activate LaTeX Workshop sidebar item to render the thumbnail of a PDF file".
[image]

I've tried to locate the LaTeX Workshop sidebar item, but I'm not sure if I'm looking in the right place or if there's a specific setting I need to enable. Could anyone provide some guidance on how to activate this sidebar item or any other potential solutions to this issue?

Normally this is the case：
[image]

Here's some additional information that might be helpful:

Visual Studio Code version:1.85.1
LaTeX Workshop version: 9.17
Operating System: win11
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and found a solution in the following post: https://blog.csdn.net/HaoZiHuang/article/details/135432722. I post here a figure for self-containedness. In my case, I just needed to click on "Refresh all viewers".
[image: Solution]

Comment: Exactly the solution! Looks like sometimes it needs refresh after compiling? Not sure how often it triggers